# printing node output in a file in Linux

Tags: node.js, linux

I have a large app output , and I should analyse the output.

It's difficult to do it on the terminal so I would print the output into a file to analyse it easier.

So how can I redirect `nodejs app.js` output into a file in Ubuntu ?

Comment: are we on server side in nodejs ? Then look at the fs (filesystem) module. You made have to make a JSON.stringify to change the json to a text-string

Comment: I'm working on local

Comment: Are you trying to capture whatever nodejs puts onto your terminal into a file instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by redirecting your app's output (stdout and stderr) to the desired file:

```
$ node app.js &> filename.txt
```

If you do this, everything that you log using **console.log()** and **console.err()** will be included in your file.

Of course, it would be better if you programmatically write to a file so you can include only what you want to keep in the file.